# Perl: Unicode в именах файлов

Tags: windows, perl, файловая-система, кодировка, локаль

Нужно, чтобы названия перл-программ содержали хотя бы кириллицу и пробелы, в идеале поддержка Unicode в именах файлов. Также нужно чтобы программа на Perl создавала файл с utf8-именем (вручную, что интересно, они благополучно создаются, хоть на китайском!).

**Дано**:

- **Perl  5.14.2** (благодаря **DWIM Perl**), **Win7 Pro** (русская)
- если надо версию Perl обновлю на пару минорных версий вверх, но не
  думаю, что проблема в этом

**Пытался**:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use utf8; 
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use feature qw/say/;

use Fcntl;
use Tie::File;

my  $добавляемый_ТЕКСТ =  q/текст на русском или вообще любой символ Unicode'а, например, 皘癲∰/  ;

my  $файл  =   "./папка/подпапка имя с пробелами/файл на русском (а лучше в Уникоде).txt";

sysopen ( ФАЙЛ, $файл, O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT ) || die "$файл cannot be opened. $!";             

say ФАЙЛ $добавляемый_ТЕКСТ;
```

Это код работает только если нет кириллицы и пробелов в путях.
Сам файл исправно создаётся в uft8 и содержимое не повреждается!

Начал копать http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-standard-preamble.html, но "утонул" и нескоро вынырну.

Сейчас пытаюсь переписать **sysopen** на **open**, но даже переписать на такую конструкцию не  получается:

```
open(  $самФАЙЛ, ">> :encoding(cp1251)", $файл  );   
say  $самФАЙЛ   $добавляемый_ТЕКСТ  ;
```

Как я понимаю **sysopen**() и **оpen**() далеко не эквиваленты, но всё же как добавить "*:encoding(КОДИРОВКА)*" к **sysopen**()?

Comment: на просторах интернета рекомендуют использовать Win32API::File для правильного кодирования имен файлов или использовать кодировку UTF-16le

Comment: @Mike, *кто прямые косые на обратные преобразует* -- винды с рождения же это умели :) Ну во всяком случае с 95, за 3.* и меньше не скажу. В исходниках даже досовских библиотек Turbo C можно посмотреть. `PATH_SEPARATOR` это уже более позднее изобретение, когда вылезло - не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Unicode file names on Windows using Perl
# Philip R Brenan at gmail dot com, Appa Apps Ltd, 2013
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

use feature ":5.16";
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use Encode qw/encode decode/;
use Win32API::File qw(:ALL);

# Create a file with a unicode name

my $e  = "\x{05E7}\x{05EA}\x{05E7}\x{05D5}\x{05D5}\x{05D4}".
         "\x{002E}\x{0064}\x{0061}\x{0074}\x{0061}"; # File name in UTF-8
my $f  = encode("UTF-16LE", $e);  # Format supported by NTFS
my $g  = eval dump($f);           # Remove UTF ness
   $g .= chr(0).chr(0);           # 0 terminate string
my $F  = Win32API::File::CreateFileW
 ($g, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, [], OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, 0); #  Create file via Win32API
say $^E if $^E;                   # Write any error message

# Write to the file

OsFHandleOpen(FILE, $F, "w") or die "Cannot open file";
binmode FILE;                      
print FILE "hello there\n";      
close(FILE);
```

Details here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7207996/1336858) and below.

Answer (score 0):

```
use open qw(:utf8);

binmode(STDIN,':utf8');

binmode(STDOUT,':utf8');

use utf8;
```

И в дескриптор файла:

```
open ФАЙЛ, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'logfile' or die;
```